# Idiomatic way of processing instances of derived classes?

Tags: python, inheritance, interface

Although, I have some years of experience programming in Python every time I encounter a problem like this I'm using the built-in isinstance function. However, I'm not sure whether this is the ideomatic way of doing these kind of things in python.

So, I have a base class that most of my instances will be.

```
class Base():
  def a(self):
    return 1
```

I also have a slightly different class that look like this:

```
class Extended(Base):
  def b(self):
    return 2
```

Now, there is a third class that might have additional functionality depending on the received argument which would be instance of one of the previous classes.

```
class User():
  def __init__(self, arg):
    ... # do some common work
    if isinstance(arg, Extended):
      ...
      # define more functionality which will call method 'b'
      # at some point during runtime (as event handler or smth)
```

Is this really the way to go with Python on this trivial example or maybe I should consider changing the interface of the Base to something like:

```
class Base2():
  supports_more_func = False

  def a(self):
    return 1

  def b(self):
    pass

class Extended2(Base2):
  supports_more_func = True

  def b(self):
    return 2

class User():
  def __init__(self, arg):
    ... # do some common work
    if arg.supports_more_func:
      ...
      # define more functionality which will call method 'b'
      # at some point during runtime (as event handler or smth)
```

Which one is the better approach according to you guy and why?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, when doing object oriented programming, using `isinstance` is rarely the way to go, especially when you're in charge of designing the classes you use, because that would be breaking [S.O.L.I.D. principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

Instead you should simply design your class to have a common well defined interface and just use it. So testing for type or for a member is rarely the way to go.

The way I'd go would be:

```
class Base2():
  def a(self):
    return 1

  def b(self):
    pass

class Extended2(Base2):
  def b(self):
    # all that extra functionality that was in User.__init__()
    return 2

class User():
  def __init__(self, arg):
    ... # do some common work
    arg.b()
```

now I guess that the part with:

```
  # define more functionality which will call method 'b'
  # at some point during runtime (as event handler or smth)
```

has some data and processing tightly coupled with `User` and not with `Extended2`, but I'm pretty sure there's an elegant way to give that data to `arg.b()` as argument.

Basically, I'd say that 99% of the time when you need to use `isinstance()` to do something, it means you have a design issue and there's a better way to do the same.

Here's some web-litterature on the topic:

- http://canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/
- https://www.quora.com/When-is-it-acceptable-to-use-isinstance-in-Python
- https://www.lynda.com/Programming-Languages-tutorials/Avoiding-isinstance/471978/502199-4.html

Comment: Thanks for the response! The thing is that I have a UI app in mind. In User class if 'arg' was Extended there should be some additional widgets showed on screen. Then if the user clicks on that additional widgets, User will transfer the call to Extended. The problem is that if 'arg' was Base there shouldn't be any additional widgets showed, so I really need a way to determine with what kind of type I'm working with... 

Interesting thins would be to know how a person working in Java or C++ would do this?